# git post-receive to manage website with generated files

Tags: git, githooks

I have a web application that I would like to bring under version control using git.  I have done this on the server with several other sites using the following strategy.

```
$ mkdir /var/git/example.git && cd /var/git/example.git
$ git init --bare
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/example.com git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
.... add files, commit, push, yada yada
```

The process works fine whenever I have done it in the past, but for this new site there is a new wrinkle for me.  This new site generates files and stores them in a directory.  The directory is writeable by the webroot.  Let's call that directory:

```
/var/www/example.com/generatedfiles/
```

My concern is that the `checkout -f` will delete this directory and I will lose all the generated content.  I also don't want that content in my git repository.

So, my question is how can I setup my post-receive hook so that it leaves the generatedfiles directory alone, but I still get the effectiveness of `checkout -f`?

Comment: We do `checkout -f` in our `post-receive` hook without it deleting existing, non-versioned directories. Have you tried?

Comment: Does the `checkout` delete anything? Just add the directory into .gitignore.

Comment: You can use gitignore option.

Comment: I have not tried yet as there is a lot of existing content that I do not want to accidentally overwrite.  I want to know that what I am doing is right beforehand.

Comment: @PeterMeth Make a sandbox repo (`git init`) and play with it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

There were some helpful suggestions in the comments, but since no one gave an answer I will give one.  If anyone who left a comment cares to answer I will mark yours as correct.

@ceejayoz was correct in that if the files and directories are not under version control then they don't get overwritten with `checkout -f`

@kan and @vpatil were correct, if I simply add the following to a file called .gitignore in the root of the repo, the generatedfiles directory will not get overwritten

```
/generatedfiles
```